# How smaz compression library works?

Tags: algorithm, redis, compression, lzw

I'm currently working for a short text compression project based on my language. But as a beginner, I also know some basic compression algorithm like LZW. But I still don't understand how [smaz](https://github.com/antirez/smaz) works. I have 2 questions:

1. How does smaz work?
2. How to build the codebook and reversed codebook?

Can any one explain it for me?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

trying to answer your questions

**How does smaz work?**
according [[1]](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Data_Compression/Dictionary_compression#Smaz),

> Smaz has a hard-wired constant built-in codebook of 254 common English
>   words, word fragments, bigrams, and the lowercase letters (except j,
>   k, q). The inner loop of the Smaz decoder is very simple:
>
> - Fetch the next byte X from the compressed file.
>
>   1. Is X == 254? Single byte literal: fetch the next byte L, and pass it straight through to the decoded text.
>   2. Is X == 255? Literal string: fetch the next byte L, then pass the following L+1 bytes straight through to the decoded text.
>   3. Any other value of X: lookup the X'th "word" in the codebook (that "word" can be from 1 to 5 letters), and copy that word to the decoded
>        text.
> - Repeat until there are no more compressed bytes left in the compressed file.
>
> Because the codebook is constant, the Smaz decoder is unable to
>   "learn" new words and compress them, no matter how often they appear
>   in the original text.

This [page](https://ayende.com/blog/172865/reverse-engineering-the-smaz-compression-library) could be helpful to understand the code.

**How to build the codebook and reversed codebook?**
[TODO](https://github.com/antirez/smaz/blob/master/TODO) file in repository and author [comments](https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/88vj7/smaz_short_strings_compression_library/) in redit poitns that the dictionary was generated by a unreleased ruby script. Also, the author explains:

> btw what the Ruby program does is to consider all the possible substrings, and even all the possible separated words, and build a
>   table of frequencies, than adjust the weight based on the string
>   length, and finally hand tuning the table to compress specific things
>   very well. I added by hand the "http://" and ".com" token for example,
>   removing the final two entries.

An alternative to your project could be the [shoco library](http://ed-von-schleck.github.io/shoco/) which supports generation of a custom compression model based on your language.

Answer (score 1):

The [smaz sources](https://github.com/antirez/smaz/blob/master/smaz.c) is only 178 lines and just 99 lines without comments and codebook tables. You should look to see how it works.

Smaz is pretty simple compression by codebook (like LZW which you know). The library contains table with most popular terms in english (lines 5 - 51 for compression table and 56 -76 for decompression) and replace this terms with indexes in compressed string. And contrary to decompress.

For example, string `the end` would compressed by 58% becouse if terms `the` would be one byte index in compression table. So 7 bytes lenght string became 4 bytes length string.

Comment: In theory, about LZW, I can understand. But as the question, I also read the source code, and still don't understand how to build the codebook (the meaning of item in this codebook).

Comment: Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_common_words_in_English or in http://www.wordfrequency.info/free.asp